# Android ConstraintLayout going offscreen

Tags: android, android-studio, android-constraintlayout

[example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWYyS.png)
[example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADbwA.png)

I just started to learn how to develop Android apps, and this issue with the ConstraintLayout has been appearing since the beginning. I'm using Android Studio 2.2.3.

As you can see from the examples above, all of the items have gone off their respective blueprint or design layout. When this happens, I cannot drag them back to where they are supposed to be.

There's no exact way to duplicate this problem. It happens seemingly at random whenever I use the ConstraintLayout. It even happens when I don't touch it. I may be off doing something else, but when I return to Android Studio, everything has gone awry. This does not happen with other layouts that I have tried.

I've tried "Invalidate caches/restart" and cleaning and rebuilding the project. The former may fix the problem with one layout, but other layouts unfortunately become affected by this problem.

Any help would be very appreciated. I don't know how many times I've redone a layout. It is quite demoralizing.

First example XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/activity_set_up"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.richl.candito6week.setUp">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/appBar"
            layout="@layout/app_bar"
            android:layout_width="384dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/benchNum"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            card_view:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/separator2" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/deadNum"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            card_view:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/separator3" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/separator3"
            android:layout_width="368dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            card_view:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/benchNum" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/squatNum"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            card_view:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/repMax_card" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/benchText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="@string/bench_press"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold"
            card_view:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/benchNum"
            card_view:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/benchNum" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/deadText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="@string/deadlift"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold"
            card_view:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/deadNum"
            card_view:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/deadNum" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/squat_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="@string/squat"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold"
            card_view:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/squatNum"
            card_view:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/squatNum" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/separator2"
            android:layout_width="368dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            card_view:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/squatNum" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/spinner_card"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
            card_view:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/trackWeights_card">

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/weightSpinner"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="4dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="191dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="75dp" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/repMax_card"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            card_view:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spinner_card">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:text="@string/what_are_your_1rm_s_for_the_following_lifts"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/setUp1Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="@string/next"
            card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/deadNum" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/trackWeights_card"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
            card_view:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appBar">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="326dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:paddingEnd="4dp"
                android:paddingStart="4dp"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:text="@string/do_you_track_your_weights_in_kilograms_or_pounds"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Second example XML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/activity_choose_accessory_workouts"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.richl.candito6week.chooseAccessoryWorkouts">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/include2"
            layout="@layout/app_bar"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
            tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
            tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/chooseAccessory_card"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/include2">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/chooseAccessory_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:text="@string/choose_your_preferred_accessory_exercises"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/chooseBack1_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="@string/upper_back_exercise_1_horizontal_pull"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/chooseAccessory_card"
            tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/chooseBack1_spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:padding="4dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/chooseBack1_view" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/chooseShoulder_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="@string/shoulder_exercise"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/chooseBack1_spinner"
            tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/shoulderExercise_spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:padding="4dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/chooseShoulder_view" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/chooseBack2_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="@string/upper_back_exercise_2_vertical_string_upper_back_exercise_1_horizontal_pull"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/shoulderExercise_spinner" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/chooseBack2_spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:padding="4dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/chooseBack2_view" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/accessoryWorkoutButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:text="@string/next"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/chooseBack2_spinner"
            tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
            tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
            tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: It's still in beta stage, so don't be surprised this is happening. Happens to me too, but I fix it sometimes by rebuilding/clean or even restarting Android Studio. It's just rendering issue in the preview, but on the actual build, it will still be as how you aligned the elements.

Comment: post your xml layout

Comment: I've noticed that views go off the preview screen in A.S., but once deployed to device, properly show on screen.